# Is there any standard or convention about implementing offset pagination with GraphQL?

Tags: pagination, graphql

GraphQL has en excellent spec available for cursor pagination (https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm ), but is there any standard or convention about how to implement a more classic offset pagination, without "connections" ? How to name resolver arguments, how total count should be returned, which pagination metadata should be returned and how, how the resulting object should be structured etc

I saw a lot of different implementations and have no clue about the "right" way to do that, if there is any.

Comment: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/ ... and more with linked docs/tuts ... classic for simple use cases ... connections by only nodes and edges+nodes, frequently both supported ... see (and use) generators, prisma etc.

Comment: @xadm are "skip" and "take" arguments names frequently used or is this only a prisma thing ?